# Python - Trabajar sobre un archivo

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estoy iniciándome en Python y en cada sentencia que intento escribir me da un error.

Me he creado un `archivo.txt` con una secuencia fasta que he descargado, con sus espacios y sus números.

Ahora intento trabajar sobre ella, haciendo pequeños cambios, en plan quitar espacios, eliminar saltos de carro.

Lo sé hacer si copio la secuencia arriba, pero abriéndola desde otro archivo no.

```
fichero = open ('/ruta del archivo.txt')

for linea in fichero:

    a=fichero.replace('\n','')

    b=a.replace(' ','')

    dna = re.sub("[0-9]", "", b)

print dna
```

Puede haber un error en los nombres que les voy asignando?

Comment: Estaba dudando en responder ya que hay dos cosas que no me quedan claras. Lo primero, es este código no es python3 como indica la etiqueta. Por otro lado, el formato FASTA sólo tiene líneas de comentarios que empiezan por `>` y secuencias DNA. Basta quitar la línea de comentario para quedarte con la secuencia de DNA. ¿Para qué quitar espacios y números? ¿O estás haciendo una pregunta más en general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con `open` estás abriendo el fichero y lo que obtienes es una referencia a él; pero la lectura la haces con cada iteración de bucle donde se mete cada línea en la variable `linea`. El `.replace()` lo tienes que emplear sobre cada línea leída, no sobre la referencia al fichero.

Te pongo un ejemplo para leer ficheros FASTA:

```
def readGenome(filename):
    genome = ''
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            # ignore header line with genome information
            if not line[0] == '>':
                genome += line.rstrip()
    return genome

genome = readGenome('lambda_virus.fa')
```

Comment: Gracias Chema, no sabía que python3 era diferente de python, pensaba que era el mismo lenguaje, perdón.

Comment: Son el mismo lenguaje, lo único que si pones [tag:python-3.x] estás especificando la versión del lenguaje que usas. El uso del `print` de tu ejemplo es de las versiones anteriores. En [tag:python-3.x] te daría error. Las etiquetas python tienen información de cómo usarlas (pasa el ratón por encima de una de ellas y espera a que te salga la ayuda). Ya te corrijo las etiquetas.